# Does Tropius' Chlorophyll work even if it's ally uses 'Sunny Day' in a double battle?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

Thanks for reading,
For some reason, when I fight a double battle using my Tropius and Numel,
Tropius' speed remains at a constant of 39 even after a few turns when Numel uses Sunny day.

Is this a glitch, or am I missing something? For Tropius' ability to work, does it itself have to use sunny day, or any pokemon's sunny day will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sunny Day (and other weather-related moves) affect the whole field, and it doesn't matter who uses the move (or whether the harsh sunlight is brought on by Sunny Day or the Drought ability).

Any stat changes in a battle are not shown when viewing a pokemon's stats summary. Are you expecting the number to go from 39 to 78? Because it won't.

Try fighting something with a speed between 39 and 78, with and without sunshine, and you should notice the difference!

Comment: Does this mean there is no definite way to confirm the improvement in speed, but there is in fact an improvement?

Comment: Try doing what I suggested in the last sentence of my answer!